# how to get div elements using click function jquery ,php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I don't know why click function not working,

**jquery code**

```
 $("[id^='msgr_']").click(function(){
     var id= $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1];
     $("#chatbox-data-"+id ).fadeIn();
 });
```

**Html code**

```
 <div id="chatbox-data-<?php echo $d['qid'];?>" class="chatbox">

   <div  style="background-color:#000; color:#fff;padding:10px;">

  title:<a><?php echo $d['title'];?></a><br>
   qid:<?php echo $d ['qid'];?>


     <span class="close">&times;</span>

    </div><br>
```

**link:**

```
 <a class="clinks msgr" style="text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;" 
  id="msgr_<?php echo $d['qid'];?>"href="javascript:void(0)">message</a>
```

when i click message link  chatbox  needs to be open but not working don't
   no  what is the problem  save me

Comment: is there value in `id` variable when you debug? Have you wrapped your `click` event with a `$(document).ready(function(){})`?

Comment: @adiga    no  $(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: try doing the following `$(document).ready(function(){   <put your click event handler here>  });`

Comment: @adiga no same results

Comment: Have you added jQuery's reference to your page? Do you see any errors in the console? Also, inspect the chatbox `div` and message `anchor` to check whether `qid`is being appended at the end of `id`

Comment: var id is working fine  i have  tried with  alert(id); there is no problem  only problem with               $("#chatbox-data-"+id ).fadeIn();  without   id(            $("#chatbox-data-" ).fadeIn(); )  chat box have been open fine with div elements  but how to append +id big quetion how

Comment: As I said, inspect the chatbox div and check the `id`. If  `$("#chatbox-data-" ).fadeIn()` is working then it's not appedning `qid` to the chatbox `id`.

Comment: Please always let us know if there are any console errors and if yes, include them. A [mcve] will also help

Comment: @adiga what is this InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElemnt

Answer (score 0):

first this is a part of your code:

```
   <div id="chatbox-data-<?php echo $d['qid'];?>" class="chatbox">

  <div  style="background-color:#000; color:#fff;padding:10px;">

   title:<a><?php echo $d['title'];?></a><br>
  qid:<?php echo $d ['qid'];?>


 <span class="close">&times;</span>

</div><br>
```

you open two div and only close one , so replace it to :

```
  <div id="chatbox-data-<?php echo $d['qid'];?>" class="chatbox">

   <div  style="background-color:#000; color:#fff;padding:10px;">

   title:<a><?php echo $d['title'];?></a><br>
    qid:<?php echo $d ['qid'];?>


    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    </div></div><br>
```

then at js code :

```
   $("[id^='msgr_']").click(function(){
    var id= $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1];
   $("#chatbox-data-"+id ).fadeIn();
   });
```

you use fadeIn to element already displayed so,no change will happen.
either to make that element `style= "display:none"` to accept `fadeIn` onclick that anchor or to change it to `fadeOut` to see effect  :

```
     $("[id^='msgr_']").click(function(){
      var id= $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1];
       $("#chatbox-data-"+id ).fadeOut();
      });
```

or

```
  $("[id^='msgr_']").click(function(){
      var id= $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1];
       $("#chatbox-data-"+id ).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
       });
```